# Page Size of Crystal Report when exporting to PDF

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have an app that exports reports to crystal before attaching them to an email and sending. For some reason when I export the report via code, it no longer seems to fit on the page (A4). Printing from the reports designer works fine

```
cryReport.SetParameterValue(thisReportParamName, thisEmailJob.external_id);
crDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = _pReportExportPath + thisEmailJob.external_id + ".pdf";
crExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
crExportOptions.DestinationOptions = crDiskFileDestinationOptions; 
crExportOptions.ExportFormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
cryReport.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.PaperA4;
cryReport.Export();
```

Is there some way i can force the export to be A4 paper size?

Comment: Then what is it changing the Paper size to if not A4? Its quite possible you might have some fields/objects/lines getting slightly longer than workable area of the report.

Comment: How about set "no printer"? I dont know how it is done programatically, but in the designer it would be: right click on report form, "design", "printer setup", check "no printer".